# How to find SNMP community string?

Tags: snmp, snmpd

I've been trying to find the SNMP community string in Ubuntu here, but haven't had much luck.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 and have followed the instructions [here](http://www.ehow.com/how_8731252_snmp-community-string-linux.html), but my /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf file has different contents than what they're talking about.

Their snmpd.conf file contains: `rocommunity [community string]`

Mine contains: `rocommunity public default -V systemonly`

That being the case, what is my community string?

Thanks!

Comment: You can set it to whatever you'd like.

Comment: Cross posted here two days ago: http://askubuntu.com/questions/352522/how-to-find-snmp-community-string

Comment: @Wesley - Sorry about that. I just really needed an answer quick for work and wasn't getting any responses over on askubuntu.

Comment: @Hank-Roughknuckles Not getting answers on AskUbuntu is a common theme there. I'll put my answer over there as well since there's no way to mark a question / answer as a duplicate across different StackExchange sites. You can mark this as the answer both here and there to help future readers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`rocommunity public default -V systemonly`

Your read-only community string is `public`. `default` represents what traffic will be accepted, which is to say all traffic will be accepted. Change `default` to be a hostname or a network address and slash annotated subnet to restrict it further (e.g. `10.4.0.0/16`). The read-only context will be restricted to the `-V systemonly` context which means only OIDS .1.3.6.1.2.1.1 and .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1 will be visible.